# Is it bad to use client SDK in backend? (Firebase cloud functions)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Cloud Function that should send a password reset email when a new user is created. I have found out how to do it using the admin SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#node.js_1) but it's confusing and not sure how it works. Found an easier and more straightforward function on the client SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email). Is it OK to call a client SDK function in the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm writing a cloud function that should send a password reset email when a new user is created.

If you want to create and maintain such a mechanism yourself, then you can go ahead and do it. But as you already noticed, there is [something](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email) that already does that. So I think you should take advantage of that.

> Is it bad to use client SDK in the backend? (Firebase cloud functions)

Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features. So it's a server-side solution, not a client-side one. None of them is a good or bad solution, it only depends on what you want to achieve.